# Running time of querying a particular document from a collection in Firebase Cloud Firestore

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am using `Google Cloud Firestore` for storing the Data. Assume I have a simple collection of `cities`.

Assume I have 10,000 City Documents stored in my `cities` Collection. What is the Running time for querying a document with a particular Id (Ex : "city_123"). Is it constant in time or it is comparable to the size of the Documents ?

Comment: 1) The screenshot you show is of the Firebase Realtime Database, but you're asking about Cloud Firestore. The two are completely different NoSQL databases, with their own characteristics. 2) This sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). One that you can easily measure yourself, but writing a minimal amount of code to perform the operation. 3) The time the operation will take depends on many variables. There's no way for us to predict it for your situation.

Comment: I just added a reference image.
All I wanted to know is whether fetching the document based on Id is a constant time or comparable to the size of the documents(In My Case 10000) ?
 I am asking about a general case scenario , where every document has the same set of variables defined

Comment: For the majority of use-cases, the main limiting factor for retrieving document will be the bandwidth of your user's device. This means that document size is the main contributing factor to the time it'll take to read the document(s).

Comment: Size of the Documents is not a factor while querying a single document based on Id ?

Comment: I can speak from personal experience whether you have 10 nodes or 100,000, the turnaround time querying a single node is pretty much instantaneous. That being said (previously said) there a lot of other factors (internet speed etc) but I think the biggest factor is *what* your queries return. Suppose you have 10 users and query for users who first names are 'Leroy'. The Max that can possibly be returned is 10. However, increase the database size to 100,000 and there's a higher chance of returning a larger dataset. The *amount* of data returned can affect the speed and your users experience.

Comment: ...to continue. But even then your query would have to return a significantly large amount of data to really be impacted in a noticeable way (like thousands of results). Going further, if you are processing the data being returned in your app; performing calculations, filtering etc, will also have an impact; the more data returned the more processing there will be. I really like this question but it's kinda OT for this site and unfortunately it's not really answerable..  I upvoted anyway :-)

Answer (score 1):

The time for querying a Collection that contains 10,000 documents is constant but the transfer time can never be constant. It depends on the size of the document that is queried. Another important factor is the bandwidth that the user has on his device. Both are contributing to the time that will take to query that document.

To reduce the time, i suggest you reduce the amount of data by filtering using one of the filtering methods. [Here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data) is the official documentation.

Comment: the query time is actually constant. The transfer time is not. The speed as the user sees it, is mostly affected by the transfer time. The scalability of the system is mostly affected by the actual query time.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen When i said time i ment transfer time. Updated my answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Firestore is designed to automatically scale based on user demand. Regardless of the size of the database, you will get the same performance out of it. Query time will not depend on the size of the database.

**Cloud Firestore performs automatic, multi-regional replication to reduce any latency.**

So in case, you query 5 docs from the dataset of size 10,000 or you query 5 docs from the dataset of size 10,000k, the query time will be same. Query time is related to the size of results to return.